# Azure Mobile Service Insert Backend Script Error

Tags: javascript, database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I want to insert raw data into the database with the following backend script:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
var queryString = "INSERT INTO sessions_res ( id , restaurant_id ,     person_number , budget , category , coordination ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + ? + ' ' + ? + ')', 4326))"; 
mssql.query(queryString, [item.id, item.restaurant_id, item.person_number, item.budget, item.category, item.longitude.toString(), item.latitude.toString()], {
    success: function () {
        request.respond(statusCodes.OK, {});
    }
});
}
```

And I received the following exception, please help:

Comment: sounds like a retriable error .. did you retry this operation?

Comment: Do your server logs (via the azure portal) show any errors?

Comment: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException'

Comment: That exception is not a server exception, it is a client exception. What does the Azure Portal show?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide to the server scripts in Mobile Services: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#table-scripts

When you are getting a client exception, it is really valuable to log each request and response to see where the issue is. Here's an example of a DelegatingHandler that you can attach to your MobileServicesClient object to do this logging: https://github.com/paulbatum/FieldEngineerLite/blob/master/FieldEngineerLite.Client/FieldEngineerLite/Helpers/LoggingHelpers.cs